# Set the button invisible in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and was going through the button documentation. I was wondering if the system knows which view I clicked on. Like this button.

```
 <Button
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/self_destruct"
 android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

For the callback function `selfDestruct`, the documentation says the view passed into the function is the one that is clicked on. So I defined my "selfDestruct" function as followed

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) 
{
    view.setVisibility(1);
}
```

So when I clicked on the button, it should have been set to invisible. But it didn't. What did I do wrong?  Or I have to explicitly pass the button "view" to the function in case that system doesn't know which one I clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view.setVisibility(View.GONE);`  try using this method.

`view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` , you can use this too, but the space occupied by the view, will not be gone out of screen. it will be just invisible.

Comment: thank you! it works! but could you tell me why it is? i thought  setvisibility takes an integer argument.

Comment: invisible value is 4, as per the link.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE ..

Comment: Always stick to the named constants instead of their raw integer values. Your code will be more readable and you will avoid problems like this one. ;)

Answer (score 1):

view.setVisibility(1); that "1" is the same as View.FOCUSABLES_TOUCH_MODE or View.FOCUS_BACKWARD

What you want to use is view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

here is the [view options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: yea, I was on that page and found 1 in a little table. Thank you anyway